# How to declare Chrome extension to handle specific URL scheme?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I'd like to write an extension that handles specific URLs that have custom scheme (myscheme://). How do I declare my extension so it is invoked on such a request and intercepts it? (The URL can be clicked, typed directly in the address bar, passed in the command line, etc.). This is probably a beginner question, but I'm a beginner!

Comment: If by "passed in the command line" you mean launching the URI scheme outside of Chrome, you can't do this with just a Chrome extension.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [JavaScript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler) that you can use for this.

```
navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto",
                                  "https://www.example.com/?uri=%s",
                                  "Example Mail");
```

Comment: This method allows redirecting to some URL, how can it be used for handling specific scheme URL by Chrome extension?

Comment: You should be able to use `chrome-extension://uuid/scheme.html?uri=%s`

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work. Please see that I've asked for a global handler, which captures requests coming from everywhere: click, address type, command line, etc.

Comment: It should work for everything. I'm getting a weird security error when I try it though. There might currently be a bug in Chrome that makes it not work.