# How to launch a Chrome Extension popup from a background thread?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup, uri

I want to write a Chrome Extension that will be monitoring for [URI link clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428963/how-to-declare-chrome-extension-to-handle-specific-url-scheme), and when it encounters that it is to launch its popup. I understand that the monitoring will be done in the background thread of the Extension, but I'm not sure how I can launch the popup from the background thread?

Think of the functionality like allowing a simple email editor in a popup - when someone clicks a mailto link, the popup appears to let user write an email and send it without taking them to a new browser window.

Comment: As of right now, this isn't possible. You can't programmatically open the popup. It can only open when you click the icon or if you map a key combo to it with the `commands` api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with `registerProtocolHandler`, but that doesn't mean you can't write your own [`content script`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html):

```
window.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.href && e.target.href.indexOf('mailto:') != -1) {
        var email = e.target.href.replace('mailto:', '');
        // open your popup when an email is clicked
        window.open(...);
    }
}, false);
```